# Question on Probability and area application in it.

Tags: probability

A business man is expecting two telephone calls . Mr.A may call any time between $2$ p.m and $4$ p.m , while Mr.B is equally likely to call any time between $2.30$ p.m and $3.15$ p.m . The probability that Mr. A calls before Mr. B is :

My Approach : I tried it by using probability of area as by plotting time of A and B in minutes on $x-y$ axis and then use the shaded area but could not find correct answer .

Please help......

Answer (score 0):

Well OP , your book has gone wrong. Ans should be $7/16$

Let Mr.A call at $2$ hrs. $x$ minutes

Mr.B call at $2$ hrs. $y$ minutes

where $x\in(0,120)$ and $y\in(30,75)$

Favorable cases when $x<y$

Now simply plot a graph with $x<y,y=75,y=30,x=120$ and $x=0,y=0$

You will get favourable area as: $\frac{1}{2}(75+30)\times 45$
With total area as $120\times45$

Giving you the answer $\frac{7}{16}$